# How do I know which sleeping jobs are safe to `kill`?

Tags: kill, sleep

I work on a linux machine connected to a cluster. If I do `top` on a terminal, I see many (~200) sleeping processes. Probably they were caused by me by inappropriately `Ctrl+C`-ing those processes.

How do I know which sleeping jobs are safe to `kill`?

**EDIT:** I can check the processes by `ps -e S`. The problem is, probably, that I do not understand the output. For example:

```
24086 pts/0    Ss+  11971:50 -tcsh
24084 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
22183 ?        Sl    10:08 /usr/bin/gedit --gapplication-service
4790 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u16:2]
1043 tty7     Ssl+  91:14 /usr/sbin/brld --nodaemon
```

And many others. How do I know that by killing them I do not cause any trouble to my machine or to other's logged-in jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at top to see your sleeping processes, you might be better off doing a `ps -ef | grep <process name>` instead of trying to get them from top. this way you will get the `pid` you need to kill the process with. a lot of the sleeping processes in top are normally system processes.

example:

```
[thebtm@localhost thebtm]# ps -ef | grep httpd
root      1257     1  0 Mar28 ?        00:00:51 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root      2920 10825  0 08:35 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
apache   16936  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16937  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16939  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16940  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20857  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20858  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20859  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20860  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   21040  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   21041  1257  0 Apr10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
[thebtm@localhost thebtm]# kill 16936
```

Comment: What is the difference between the command that you suggest, and `ps -e S`? In my case, the former returns only the process just called, while the second returns a long list of processes.

Comment: That i something i would have to look into, I am just used to using the `ps -ef` command to view all active processes on the system.

Comment: please see the edit of my question.